# Drawing curves using libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm using `libgdx` trying to draw some curves using this [doc](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Path-interface-%26-Splines).

But when I render, its just a straight line, any ideas why it doesn't curve?

I'm assuming `myCatmull.valueAt` should populate correct points on curve.

```
public class IABezier {

    Vector2[] points = new Vector2[100];

    public IABezier() {

        Vector2[] dataSet = new Vector2[2];
        dataSet[0] = new Vector2(10.0f, 10.0f);
        dataSet[1] = new Vector2(20.0f, 20.0f);

        CatmullRomSpline < Vector2 > myCatmull = new CatmullRomSpline < Vector2 > (dataSet, true);
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {

            points[i] = new Vector2();
            myCatmull.valueAt(points[i], ((float) i) / ((float) 100 - 1));
        }
    }

    public void draw(ShapeRenderer sRenderer) {

        sRenderer.begin(ShapeType.Line);
        sRenderer.identity();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100 - 1; ++i) {

            sRenderer.line(points[i], points[i + 1]);
        }
        sRenderer.end();
    }
}
```

Rendered ..

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [catmullrom spline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centripetal_Catmull%E2%80%93Rom_spline) requires at least four samples. So you'll have to add a few more samples to see the actual curve.

```
    Vector2[] dataSet = new Vector2[6];
    dataSet[0] = new Vector2(10.0f, 10.0f);
    dataSet[1] = new Vector2(20.0f, 20.0f);
    dataSet[2] = new Vector2(20.0f, 10.0f);
    dataSet[3] = new Vector2(10.0f, 20.0f);
    dataSet[4] = new Vector2(15.0f, 15.0f);
    dataSet[5] = new Vector2(25.0f, 25.0f);
```

[Here's an example which you can copy, paste and run](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/PathTest.java#L73).